# How to replace a custom date string in a text file

Tags: ubuntu, sed, awk

I've looked through several tutorials and a couple of StackOverflow posts, but I've not seen any examples using sed or awk which use dates. I have a text file that contains this as the first line, I need to replace the date with the current date and time via script; what is the easiest way to do this in Linux?

```
TS: 2014-03-31 13:56:01
```

I can use any tool available in a standard Ubuntu install such as sed or awk.

Comment: Is it this specific date or all dates with this format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplistic approach would be to just use `sed` and replace the string with the correct one. So, if the current time is `2014-04-02 21:34:13` you could simply run

```
sed 's/2014-03-31 13:56:01/2014-04-02 21:34:13/' file
```

Since, presumably, you want to do this dynamically, you can pass `sed` the result of the relevant `date` call instead:

```
sed "s/2014-03-31 13:56:01/$(date '+%F %T')/" file
```

Note the double quotes (`"`) around the `sed` command, those are needed for the `date` command to be run.

Answer (score 3):

To replace the first line with the expected timestamp, just use

```
sed "1c TS: $(date '+%F %T')"
```

The 1 at the beginning means the first line, `c` means "replace the line with the following string". `$(...)`  inserts the output of the given command, see `man date` for details.